# Complex number computational error grows as the size of matrix increase

Tags: python-3.x, precision, complex-numbers, computation

If I have two small complex matrices, the complex number multiplication is fine even when I do it manually (Breaking the complex numbers into real and imaginary parts and do the multiplication respectively).

```
import numpy as np
a_shape = (3,10)
b_shape = (10,3)

# Generating the first complex matrix a
np.random.seed(0)
a_real = np.random.randn(a_shape[0], a_shape[1])
np.random.seed(1)
a_imag = np.random.randn(a_shape[0], a_shape[1])
a = a_real + a_imag*1j

# Generating the second complex matrix b
np.random.seed(2)
b_real = np.random.randn(b_shape[0], b_shape[1])
np.random.seed(3)
b_imag = np.random.randn(b_shape[0], b_shape[1])
b = b_real + b_imag*1j

# 1st approach to do complex multiplication
output1 = np.dot(a,b)
# Manaul complex multiplication
output_real = np.dot(a.real,b.real) - np.dot(a.imag,b.imag)
np.array_equal(output1.real, output_real) # the results are the same

>>> True
```

However, if my matrices are bigger, the results obtained by `np.(a,b)` and multiplying it manually are different.

```
a_shape = (3,500)
b_shape = (500,3)

# Generating the first complex matrix a
np.random.seed(0)
a_real = np.random.randn(a_shape[0], a_shape[1])
np.random.seed(1)
a_imag = np.random.randn(a_shape[0], a_shape[1])
a = a_real + a_imag*1j

# Generating the second complex matrix b
np.random.seed(2)
b_real = np.random.randn(b_shape[0], b_shape[1])
np.random.seed(3)
b_imag = np.random.randn(b_shape[0], b_shape[1])
b = b_real + b_imag*1j

# 1st approach to do complex multiplication
output1 = np.dot(a,b)
# 2nd approach to do complex multiplication
output_real = np.dot(a.real,b.real) - np.dot(a.imag,b.imag)
np.array_equal(output1.real, output_real)
>>> False
```

I am asking this because I need to do some complex number multiplication in `pytorch`. `pytorch` doesn't support complex number natively, so I need to do it manually for the real and imagery components.

Then the result is slightly off than using `np.dot(a,b)`
Any resolution to this problem?

### Differences between the two calculations

```
output1.real - output_real
>>>array([[-3.55271368e-15, -2.48689958e-14,  1.06581410e-14],
       [-1.06581410e-14, -5.32907052e-15, -7.10542736e-15],
       [ 0.00000000e+00, -2.84217094e-14, -7.10542736e-15]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how small the differences are but I suspect what you are seeing has nothing to do with complex numbers but with the nature of floating point arithmetic.

In particular floating point addition is not associative, that is we do not necessarily have

```
(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
```

This would explain what you are seeing, as what you are doing is comparing

```
Sum{ Ra[i]*Rb[i] - Ia[i]*Ib[i]}
```

and

```
Sum{ Ra[i]*Rb[i]} - Sum{ Ia[i]*Ib[i]}
```

(where Ra[i] is the real part of a[i] etc)

One thing to try to see that this is the problem is to restrict the real and complex parts of the numbers to be, say, a whole number of sixteenths. With such numbers -- as long as you don't add an outrageous number (many many billions) of them -- double precision floating point arithmetic will be exact and so you should get identical results. For example in C you could generate such numbers by generating a bunch of random integers between say -16 and 16 and then divining each by the (double precision) number 16.0, to get a double precision number between -1 and 1 that is a whole number of sixteenths.

Comment: Sorry that my background is not computer science, I just use python to do some scientific computations occasionally. Can you explain more what is the meaning of "a whole number of sixteenths" ? Is it basically to try double datatype instead of float?

Comment: I mean that your random numbers, themselves floats or doubles, should be of the form n/16 where n is an integer between -16 and 16 say. I'm afraid I don't know how to do this (or anything really) in python. Anyway it would help clarify your problem if you could say what you mean by 'slightly off', that is how big are the outputs and how big is the difference?

Comment: I have added the difference between the two array. The difference is actually quite small.

Comment: Do you know how to do that n/16 in other languages? If there's a code on this, I think I am able to figure out something similar in python.